# How to project symmetric matrix $X$ to semi-definite cone, and preserve, $X_{n,n}=1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have a symmetric matrix, $X$, which satisfy the constraints, $X_{n,n}=1$. I want to project this matrix on semidefinite cone. But when I do this, $X_{n,n}$ element is no longer, equal to 1.

How can project this matrix to semidefinite cone, and at the same time preserve, this constraint?

I have done this, but I'm not sure that it is correct. First project the matrix, and then $X= X /X_{n,n}$. Is it correct? if yes why? otherwise how to do this projection?
Diagonal elements of matrix, $X$, before projection are all positive.

For the example provided in comments by @user251257, $X=[\begin{matrix} 2&2\\2&1\end{matrix}]$, projection on to SD cone is, $Xp=[\begin{matrix} 2.2127&1.7276\\1.7276&1.3489\end{matrix}]$. And dividing by $X_{n,n}$, $Xp=[\begin{matrix} 1.64.4&1.2808\\1.2808&1.0\end{matrix}]$.

I did what user, @AC_mosek, suggested in comments, and formulated the following problem, 
\begin{align}
minimize \quad \Vert x-[\begin{matrix} 2&2\\2&1\end{matrix}]\Vert^2_{F}\\
s.t. x>=0 \\
x_{2,2}=1
\end{align}
The result is, 
$X=[\begin{matrix} 2.3147&1.5214\\1.5214&1.0000\end{matrix}].$
 Which is different from what, I have done previously.

The Question is How to Obtain, an approximation of this matrix, not necessarily very accurate, WITHOUT Solving an SDP?

Comment: Elements of diagonal are all positive.

Comment: I have a semidefinite matrix, some elements of it is changed, so it is no longer semidefinite, but it's diagonal elements are kept positive and so your example is not possible.

Comment: What does your method produce for $X = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Just cast the problem as an SDP an use an SDP solver. The projection must minimize the distance from the initial matrix.

Comment: @AC_MOSEK that's a valid option.  but it does not improve the understanding of the problem...

Comment: Actually an SDP formulation is the clearest way: you search for an SDP matrix which minimize the distance from the given one, which is the very definition of projecting. Then you can add constraints on the single entries. See http://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html. Your approach won't necessarily give you the projection, but an SDP not to far.

Comment: I am trying to solve an SDP with Augmented lagrangian approach to obtain  speed. Therefore, I don't want to model the a subproblem as an SDP.

Comment: have you compared your approach with a (more) accurate projection? How do they effect the run time and accuracy of the complete method? Most of the time you don't need intermediate values with high accuracy.

Comment: Yes. I compared and I am agree with you. In my experiments, there wasn't a large difference between those two.

Comment: Yes. I compared and I am agree with you. In my experiments, there wasn't a large difference between those two.  But I don't know if it is enough in last iterations of optimization.